# BinaryFormatter.Deserialize. Changing Type

Tags: c#, serialization

I am using Binary serialization.

In one instance I am serializing a `Dictionary<SubType, string>`, however I now need to change it to `Dictionary<BaseType, string>` for later versions, whilst still being able to deserialize the former.

I've looked into SerializationBinder but I'm not sure it's what I need.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You will need both a binder and a surrogate, as in one of my previous answers here 


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866351/how-to-serialize-system-diagnostics-stopwatch/1867022#1867022